# Capybara with Test::Unit, i18n tables are not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, capybara, integration-testing, testunit

I'm writing integration tests  with Capybara within the good ol' Test::Unit framework.
The project's views contain *i18n*-ed labels, which are not translated when running the tests.
Apparently the translation tables are not loaded in the test environment.

Using: `rake translations:load RAILS_ENV=test` did nothing.